# $\int_a^b \frac{(x-a)^p(b-x)^{1-p}}{\text{P}(x)} dx$ using contour integration and residue theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus, branch-cuts

So a while ago I came across these types of integrals that has the form of
$$
I = \int_a^b (x-a)^p(b-x)^{1-p}dx
$$
Where $a$, $b$ and $p$ are real numbers, $a<b$ and $0<p<1$. And those types integral has a closed form, namely
$$
I = \frac{\pi}{2}p(1-p)(b-a)^2\csc(p\pi)
$$
But then I also came across integrals like these along the way
$$
\int_0^3 \frac{x^{3/4}(3-x)^{1/4}}{5-x}dx
$$
So I asked myself, is there a more generalized form of the $I$ integral, namely
$$
J = \int_a^b \frac{(x-a)^p(b-x)^{1-p}}{\text{P}(x)} dx
$$
Where $\text{P}(x)$ is any polynomial.

To begin with, I decided to make a more concise (?) definition of the function
$$
\text{P}(x) = \prod_{k=1}^n (x-c_k)^{q_k}
$$
Where $c_k$ is the $k$-th root of $\text{P}(x)$ and $q_k$ is the $k$-th root's multiplicity. $c_1 \not = c_2 \not = c_3 \not = \ldots \not = c_n$, $c_k \not \in (a, b)$, and if $a$ or $b$ is a root of $\text{P}(x)$ then they can't have a multiplicity of 2 or higher

First off, I'll analyze this function
$$
f(z) = \frac{(z-a)^p (b-z)^{1-p}}{\text{P}(z)} \\
= \frac{|z-a|^p |b-z|^{1-p}}{\text{P}(z)} e^{i(p\arg(z-a) + (1-p)\arg(b-z))}
$$
The poles of this function are $z = c_k$ with order $q_k$ for $k = 1,2,3,\ldots, n$

To begin, I integrated $f(z)$ over the dogbone contour
[image]

Which means I'll have
$$
\oint_{\text{Dogbone}} f(z) dz = \left(\int_{\gamma_1} + \int_{\gamma_2} + \int_{\mu_1} + \int_{\mu_2}\right) f(z) dz
$$
If we call the radius of the $\mu$ paths $\varepsilon$, and have it approach 0, then both integrals over $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ will go to 0 also. The integral over $\gamma_1$ will be $J$ and the integral over $\gamma_2$ will be $-e^{(1-p)2\pi} J$.

Which means
$$
\oint_{\text{Dogbone}} f(z) dz = \left(1 - e^{(1-p)2\pi}\right) J
$$
Now, to continue, we can inflate the contour into this
[image: Thanks Diger for pointing out the mistakes in the inflated contour]

I'll call the big circular contour $\Gamma$ and the small ones surrounding the poles at $c_k$ $\omega_k$. Which means we'll have
$$
\left(1 - e^{(1-p)2\pi}\right) J = \left(\oint_\Gamma + \sum_{k=1}^n \oint_{\omega_k}\right) f(z) dz
$$
For the $\omega$ integrals, we can simply use residue theorem for higher order poles
$$
\oint_{\omega_k} f(z) dz = - \frac{2\pi i}{(q_k - 1)!} \lim_{z \rightarrow c_k} \partial_z^{q_k - 1} (z-c_k)^{q_k} f(z)
$$
Plugging it back into the equation
$$
\left(1 - e^{(1-p)2\pi}\right) J = \oint_\Gamma f(z) dz - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2 \pi i}{(q_k - 1)!} \lim_{z \rightarrow c_k} \partial_z^{q_k - 1} (z-c_k)^{q_k} f(z)
$$

Now, my main problem is the final integral. I know that it'll be the residue of $f(z)$ at infinity, I know there's a formula for it, but I have no idea of how to evaluate such residues. My guess is that it'll some how evaluate to 0, but still, I have no idea how that'll be the answer.

---

**26/2 Edit:** Fixed some of the mistakes in calculation + Thanks to @Diger for pointing out the mistake in the inflated contour

Comment: As a side idea, you can get the definite bounds with substitutions for $\int_0^a$. For this, the  DLMF has this [hypergeometric function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.16#ii)

Comment: You haven't been careful with the branch cuts, I don't think. Your integrand doesn't seem to be meromorphic inside or outside the dogbone (so, the residue theorem will come crashing down). Yes, I know this can sometimes be fixed, but you should make explicit how you actually define $\arg$

Comment: @FShrike I see, branch cuts, defining args such are still uneasy concepts for me to grasp so I usually get a bit of trouble when doing contour integration with functions like these

Comment: I think your small circles $\omega_k$ have the wrong orientation in the figure.

Comment: @Diger I think the orientation is right? It's more of that I mixed up the signs (which I have fixed just now)

Comment: I mean, when you inflate the dogbone contour to a large circle encircling the poles counter-clockwise, you gotta subtract these contributions by encircling them clockwise. As it stands now, your contour gives contributions due to the cut, the poles + the poles again by the way you orientied these little circles.

Comment: Oh right, yeah I got a little bit confused, you're right on this one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}\newcommand{\res}{\operatorname{Res}}$Define $z\mapsto z^p$ via the principal logarithm $(-\pi\le\arg z<\pi)$ and $z\mapsto z^{1-p}$ via the logarithm induced by $0\le\arg<2\pi$. Let's call these two argument functions $\arg_1,\arg_2$ respectively.

Let's take a polynomial $\lambda$ which has no roots on $[a,b]$ (no assumptions other than that). $p$ is in $(0,1)$ and it is important that $b>a\ge0$. The case $a=0$ requires special attention in the final case for linear $\lambda$.

Then: $f:\Bbb C\to\hat{\Bbb C}$, $z\mapsto(z-a)^p(b-z)^{1-p}\lambda(z)^{-1}$ is meromorphic outside of $[a,b]$. This depends in an essential way on $\arg_1(-x)=-\pi$ when $x$ is a positive real and on the combination $p\arg_1+(1-p)\arg_2$.

You want to know the value of $\res(f,\infty)$. Assuming the rest of your work is correct, knowledge of this will give you the value of your integral.

Let $R$ be a real number larger than the modulus of every root of $\lambda$.

If $|z|\ge R$ then $|f|=\frac{|z|}{|\lambda(z)|}\cdot|1-a/z|^p\cdot|1-b/z|^{1-p}$. *If $\lambda$ has degree greater than two*, then: $$|z\cdot f(z)|\overset{|z|\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$

Which is a sufficient condition for $\res(f,\infty)=0$, so you get to ignore this term

More generally, if $f$ is holomorphic on some large annulus and vanishes as $|z|\to\infty$ then $-\lim_{|z|\to\infty}z\cdot f(z)=\res(f,\infty)$. This is justified by the "series expansion at infinity". We can apply this when the degree of $\lambda$ is two: say, $\lambda(z)=\alpha\cdot z^2+\beta\cdot z+\gamma$ where $\alpha\neq0$.

Then: $$\begin{align}\res(f,\infty)&=-\lim_{|z|\to\infty}\frac{z\cdot |z|}{\alpha\cdot z^2+\beta\cdot z+\gamma}|1-a/z|^p|1-b/z|^{1-p}e^{ip\arg_1(z-a)+i(1-p)\arg_2(b-z)}\\&=-\lim_{|z|\to\infty}\frac{1}{\alpha\cdot\frac{z}{|z|}}e^{ip\arg_1(z-a)+i(1-p)\arg_2(b-z)}\end{align}$$

If $z$ is on the negative real axis, the expression is $\frac{1}{-\alpha}e^{-i\pi p}$. This is cheating really, but since the limit must exist, it in particular must equal the value as $|z|\to\infty$ in the negative real axis so we can conclude: $$\res(f,\infty)=\frac{e^{-\pi ip}}{\alpha}$$

Finally, say $\lambda(z)=\alpha\cdot z+\beta$ is linear, where $\alpha\neq0$. Then we need a different approach, as $f$ no longer vanishes as $|z|\to\infty$. The definition $\res(f,\infty)=-\res(f(1/z)/z^2,0)$ becomes useful now.

---

There are some subtle aspects in the evaluation below. I casually pretend the things we are used to from real analysis apply for complex numbers, but this is not so. I mention the subtleties at the end.

---

If $\gamma:=\beta/\alpha$, then: $$\frac{1}{z^2}f(1/z)=\frac{e^{\pi i(1-p)}}{\alpha\cdot z^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\gamma z}(1-az)^p(1-bz)^{1-p}$$

Expand in series: $$\frac{1}{z^2}f(1/z)=-\frac{e^{-i\pi p}}{\alpha\cdot z^2}\cdot(1-\gamma z+o(z))(1-paz+o(z))(1-(1-p)bz+o(z))$$

We want to extract the $z^{-1}$ coefficient: $$-\frac{e^{-i\pi p}}{\alpha}(-\gamma-pa-(1-p)b)$$

Concluding: $$\res(f,\infty)=\frac{e^{-i\pi p}}{\alpha}\cdot(p(b-a)-b-\gamma)$$

This last expression, for example, gives the correct value of the integral for the example on Wikipedia (which is much less carefully done, I might add).

We can witness the formula for the quadratic case in action for the following situation (exercise):

> If $-1<p<2$ and $\xi>0$ then: $$\int_0^1\frac{x^p(1-x)^{1-p}}{x^2+\xi^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\=\pi\csc(\pi p)\left[\xi^{p-1}(1+\xi^2)^{\frac{1-p}{2}}\sin\left(\frac{\pi p}{2}+(1-p)\arctan(\xi)\right)-1\right]$$This should be understood in a limiting sense for $p=0,1$.
>
> I have also numerically verified this.
>
> So if $|\phi|<\pi/2$, $-2<p<1$: $$\int_0^1\frac{x^{p+1}(1-x)^{-p}}{x^2+\cot^2\phi}\,\mathrm{d}x=\pi\csc(\pi p)[1-\cos(\phi)^p\cos(p\cdot\phi)]$$

---

**NOTE:** I used the equalities $(1-az)^p/z^p=((1/z)-a)^p$, $(bz-1)^{1-p}/z^{1-p}=(b-(1/z))^{1-p}$ and $(1/z^p)\cdot(1/z^{1-p})=1/z$. These are actually quite subtle: so subtle, that they are not even always correct. However, I leave it as an exercise in geometric reasoning to show that the *product* of all these ‘equations’ is a genuine equation *for small $z$*.

Expanding in binomial series is also subtle. I presented it in the simplest, but technically misleading, way. So long as $|z|<1/a$, $(1-az)^p$ is holomorphic and we can do the usual Taylor expansion. But for small $z$, $(1-bz)^{1-p}$ is **not** holomorphic. *But*, $(bz-1)^{1-p}$ *is* holomorphic for small $z$ and we get the usual Taylor series *multiplied by a factor of $(-1)^{1-p}=-e^{-i\pi p}$*.

Phew!

Comment: I just realized that having no roots on $[a,b]$ is a better idea honestly, since if the polynomial has single roots of either $a$ or $b$, you'll just get a variation of this integral

Comment: @mils I’ve corrected a minor sign error in my formula for the quadratic case. I’ve also added an example integral where we can use the residue at infinity calculation for the quadratic case to evaluate it.

Answer (score 3):

I once wrote down the solution for $n=1$, but it should be generalizable. $m=1$ in your case.

Find the closed form for
\begin{align*}
I(x)=\frac{\Gamma(p+1)\Gamma(m-p+1)}{\Gamma(m+2)} \, {\rm _2F_1}\left(n,p+1;m+2;x\right)=\int_0^{1} \frac{t^p\left(1-t\right)^{m-p}}{\left(1-xt\right)^n} \, {\rm d}t \, ,
\end{align*}
with $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\Re(p)\in(-1,m+1)$ and $x\in D_1(0)$.

**solution:** We start by considering the integral
\begin{align}
J(x)=\oint_C \frac{z^p (1-z)^{m-p}}{(1-xz)^n} \, {\rm d}z \tag{1}
\end{align}
where $C=C_1+\gamma_1+C_2+\gamma_2$ is the dog-bone contour with $C_1=(-i\epsilon,1-i\epsilon)$, $\gamma_1=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z-1|=\epsilon \land \Re(z-1)\geq 0\}$, $C_2=(1+i\epsilon,i\epsilon)$, $\gamma_2=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=\epsilon \land \Re(z)\leq 0\}$. The integrand has cuts and poles in the complex plane, but we are free to choose the discontinuity of $z\mapsto z^p$ to be $(-\infty,0)$ and that of $z\mapsto z^{m-p}$ to be $(0,\infty)$, which means $z\mapsto (1-z)^{m-p}$ has a cut on $(-\infty,1)$. Furthermore the denominator leads to poles of order $n$ at $z=1/x$ and has no cuts. We may also assume $1/x\notin \bar{D}_1(0)$. In order to determine the cut of the integrand, we need to analyze the combined behaviour of $z^p(1-z)^{m-p}$ by considering the phase of this expression as we cross the three segments $(-\infty,0)$, $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$. Writing $z=t\pm i0$, we find
\begin{align*}
t\in(-\infty,0) : \quad \arg\left( (t\pm i0)^p(1-t\mp i0)^{m-p} \right) &= \begin{cases} \pi p + 2\pi(m-p) \quad &\text{if} \quad z=t+i0 \\ -\pi p + 0 \quad &\text{if} \quad z=t-i0 \end{cases} \\
t\in(0,1) : \quad \arg\left( (t\pm i0)^p(1-t\mp i0)^{m-p} \right) &= \begin{cases} 0 + 2\pi(m-p) \quad &\text{if} \quad z=t+i0 \\ 0 + 0 \quad &\text{if} \quad z=t-i0 \end{cases} \\
t\in(1,\infty) : \quad \arg\left( (t\pm i0)^p(1-t\mp i0)^{m-p} \right) &= \begin{cases} 0 + \pi(m-p) \quad &\text{if} \quad z=t+i0 \\ 0 + \pi(m-p) \quad &\text{if} \quad z=t-i0 \end{cases}
\end{align*}
and since multiples of $2\pi$ leave the argument invariant, the only case that leads to a discontinuity is $t\in(0,1)$. Furthermore, for the given values of $p$, it is easy to see that the integrals over $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ vanish in the limit $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. Then continuing with Equation (1), it follows
\begin{align}
\notag J(x) &= \int_{-i0}^{1-i0} \frac{z^p (1-z)^{m-p}}{(1-xz)^n} \, {\rm d}z + \int_{1+i0}^{i0} \frac{z^p (1-z)^{m-p}}{(1-xz)^n} \, {\rm d}z \\
\notag &= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{t^p (1-t)^{m-p}}{(1-xt)^n} \, {\rm d}t - e^{-i2\pi p} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{t^p (1-t)^{m-p}}{(1-xt)^n} \, {\rm d}t \\
&= \left(1 - e^{-i2\pi p} \right) I(x) \tag{2} \, .
\end{align}
On the other hand, we may now solve Equation (1) by the residue theorem. Since $1/x$ is outside the unit disk, we can deform $C$ to the unit circle $|z|=1$ and substitute $z=1/z'$
\begin{align}
J(x)=\oint_{|z'|=1} \frac{z'^{-p-2} (1-1/z')^{m-p}}{(1-x/z')^n} \, {\rm d}z' = \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{z^{n-m-2} (z-1)^{m-p}}{(z-x)^n} \, {\rm d}z \tag{3}
\end{align}
where a minus sign was absorbed to reverse the orientation of the contour back to run counter-clockwise. We can now see, that the cut on the RHS of Equation (3) is outside the unit disk and we can use the residue theorem for the singularities at $z=0$ and $z=x$ inside the unit circle
\begin{align}
 J(x)=2\pi i \, \underbrace{{\rm Res} \left( \frac{z^{n-m-2} (z-1)^{m-p}}{(z-x)^n} \right)_{z=0}}_{=R_0} + 2\pi i \, \underbrace{{\rm Res} \left( \frac{z^{n-m-2} (z-1)^{m-p}}{(z-x)^n} \right)_{z=x}}_{=R_x} \, .
\end{align}
For the residue at $z=0$ we find
\begin{align*}
 R_0&=\frac{e^{i\pi(n+m-p)}}{x^n} \, {\rm Res} \left( \frac{z^{n-m-2}(1-z)^{m-p}}{(1-z/x)^n} \right)_{z=0} \\
 &=\frac{e^{i\pi(n+m-p)}}{x^n} \, {\rm Res} \left( z^{n-m-2} \sum_{k,l=0}^\infty \binom{m-p}{k}\binom{-n}{l} (-z)^k (-z/x)^l \right)_{z=0} \\
 &= \frac{e^{-i\pi p}}{x^n} \sum_{\substack{k,l=0 \\ k+l+n-m-2=-1}}^\infty \binom{m-p}{k}\binom{-n}{l} (-1)^{k+l+n+m} x^{-l} \\
 &= -e^{-i\pi p} \sum_{\substack{l=0}}^{m+1-n} \binom{m-p}{m+1-n-l}\binom{-n}{l} x^{-l-n}
\end{align*}
and similarly at $z=x$
\begin{align*}
 R_x&=\frac{1}{(n-1)!} \frac{{\rm d}^{n-1}}{{\rm d}z^{n-1}} \, z^{n-m-2} (z-1)^{m-p} \bigg|_{z=x} \\
 &= \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k} \left( \frac{{\rm d}^{n-1-k}}{{\rm d}x^{n-1-k}} \, x^{n-m-2} \right) \left( \frac{{\rm d}^{k}}{{\rm d}x^{k}} \, (x-1)^{m-p} \right) \\
 &=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-m-2}{k-m-1} \binom{m-p}{k} x^{k-m-1} (x-1)^{m-p-k} \\
 &=-e^{-i\pi p}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-m-2}{k-m-1} \binom{m-p}{k} (-x)^{k-m-1} (1-x)^{m-p-k} \, .
\end{align*}
With Equation (2) this finally gives
\begin{align*}
 I(x)&=-\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi p)} \sum_{\substack{l=0}}^{m+1-n} \binom{m-p}{m+1-n-l}\binom{-n}{l} x^{-l-n} \\
 &\quad - \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi p)} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-m-2}{k-m-1} \binom{m-p}{k} (-x)^{k-m-1} (1-x)^{m-p-k} \, .
\end{align*}

Comment: Interesting, I'll have a read through this impressive calculation.

Answer (score 2):

These integrals can be transformed into integrals over the positive real line by the substitution $u = \frac{x-a}{b-x} $ and then evaluated using a keyhole contour.

For example, let's look at the case $$ \int_{a}^{b} \frac{(x-a)^{p}(b-x)^{1-p}}{x-c} \, \mathrm dx$$ where $a,b, c \in \mathbb{R}$, $-1<p<2$ ,  $b > a $,  $c \notin[a,b] $.

Making the substitution $u = \frac{x-a}{b-x}$, the integral becomes $$\frac{(a-b)^{2}}{b-c} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{u^{p}}{(u+1)^{2}}\frac{1}{u+\frac{a-c}{b-c}} \, \mathrm du. $$

Using the branch of the logarithm where $0 \le \arg(z) < 2 \pi$, let's integrate the function $$ f(z) = \frac{z^{p}}{(z+1)^{2}} \frac{1}{z+ \frac{a-c}{b-c}}$$ around a keyhole contour that has the keyhole along the positive real axis.

We get

$$ \begin{align}  \oint f(z) \, \mathrm dz &= \left(1-e^{2 \pi i p}\right)\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{u^{p}}{(u+1)^{2}} \frac{1}{u+ \frac{a-c}{b-c}} \, \mathrm du \\ &= 2 \pi i \left( \operatorname{Res}[f(z), -1] +\operatorname{Res}\left[f(z), - \frac{a-c}{b-c}\right]\right) \\ &= 2 \pi i \left(  \frac{\partial }{\partial z} \, \frac{z^{p}}{z+ \frac{a-c}{b-c}} \Bigg|_{-1} + e^{\pi i  p} \left(\frac{a-c}{b-c} \right)^{p} \frac{(b-c)^{2}}{(a-b)^{2}}  \right) \\ &=  2 \pi i \, e^{\pi i p}\left( -\frac{(b-c)\left((a-b)p+b-c \right)}{(a-b)^{2}}+ \left(\frac{a-c}{b-c} \right)^{p} \frac{(b-c)^{2}}{(a-b)^{2}}  \right). \end{align}$$

Therefore, $$ \int_{a}^{b} \frac{(x-a)^{p}(b-x)^{1-p}}{x-c} \, \mathrm dx=  \pi \, \csc(\pi p) \left(\left( (a-b)p+b-c \right)- \left(\frac{a-c}{b-c} \right)^{p} (b-c)\right). $$

If $p=0$ or $p=1$, the right side of the equation should be treated as a limit.

---

For $a= 0$, $b=3$, $c=5$, and $p = \frac{3}{4}$,  we have $$\begin{align} \int_{0}^{3} \frac{x^{3/4}(3-x)^{1/4} }{x-5} \, \mathrm dx  &= \sqrt{2} \pi  \left(-\frac{17}{4}   +2 \left(\frac{5}{2} \right)^{3/4} \right) \\ & = \frac{\sqrt{2} \pi}{4} \left(-17 + 8 \left(\frac{5}{2} \right)^{3/4} \right) \\ &= \frac{\sqrt{2} \pi}{4} \left(-17 + 40^{3/4} \right), \end{align}$$ which agrees with Example 6 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#Applications_of_integral_theorems).

---

Similarly, the substitution $u = \frac{x-a}{b-x}$, shows that  $$\int_{a}^{b} \frac{(x-a)^{p}(b-x)^{1-p}}{(x-c)(x-d)} \, \mathrm dx = \frac{(a-b)^{2}}{(b-c)(b-d)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{u^{p}}{u+1} \frac{\mathrm du}{\left( u+ \frac{a-c}{b-c}\right) \left( u+\frac{a-d}{b-d}\right)}, $$ where $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$, $-1 < p < 2$, $a < b$, $c \ne d$, and $c, d, \ne [a,b]$.

Integrating the function $$g(z) = \frac{z^{p}}{(z+1) \left(z+ \frac{a-c}{b-c} \right) \left(\frac{a-d}{b-d} \right)} $$ around the same keyhole contour as before, we get

$\begin{align} \oint g(z) \, \mathrm dz &= \left(1-e^{2 \pi i p} \right) \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{u^{p}}{u+1} \frac{\mathrm du}{\left( u+ \frac{a-c}{b-c}\right) \left( u+\frac{a-d}{b-d}\right)} \\ &= 2 \pi i \left(\operatorname{Res}[g(z), -1] + \operatorname{Res} \left[g(z), -\frac{a-c}{b-c} \right] + \operatorname{Res}\left[g(z), - \frac{a-d}{b-d} \right]\right) \\ &= \small 2 \pi i \left(e^{\pi i p} \, \frac{(b-c)(b-d)}{(a-b)^{2}} + e^{ \pi i p} \left(\frac{a-c}{b-c} \right)^{p} \, \frac{(b-c)^{2}(b-d)}{(a-b)^{2}(c-d)} - e^{i \pi p} \left(\frac{a-d}{b-d} \right)^{p} \,   \frac{(b-c)(b-d)^{2}}{(a-b)^{2}(c-d)} \right). \end{align}$

Therefore, $$\int_{a}^{b} \frac{(x-a)^{p}(b-x)^{1-p}}{(x-c)(x-d)} \, \mathrm dx = - \pi \csc(\pi p) \left(1+ \left(\frac{a-c}{b-c} \right)^{p} \, \frac{b-c}{c-d} - \left(\frac{a-d}{b-d} \right)^{p} \, \frac{b-d}{c-d} \right).$$