# Calculate the integral $\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{1-p}(1-x)^p}{(1+x)^2}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Calculate the integral
$$\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{1-p}(1-x)^p}{(1+x)^2}dx, \; -1<p<2$$

My attempt: I tried to use the Laplace transform

$$\mathcal{L}\left \{ \frac{x^{1-p}(1-x)^p}{(1+x)^2} \right \}(s)=\int_0^1 \frac{x^{1-p}(1-x)^p}{(1+x)^2}e^{-sx}dx=\int_0^\infty e^{-sx}\frac{x^{1-p}(1-x)^p}{(1+x)^2}dx=\int_0^\infty e^{-sx}\int_0^\infty e^{-tu}\frac{(tu)^{1-p}[(1-t)+(1-u)]^p}{(1+tu)^2}dudt$$

I don't know what to do next. Is it possible to reduce it to a beta function? This integral is very similar to this function. But I haven't been able to find any substitute

Comment: More generally there is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4646193)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Substitute $x=\frac1{1+y}$
\begin{align}
I=&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{1-p}(1-x)^p}{(1+x)^2}dx
=\int_0^\infty\frac{y^p}{(1+y)(2+y)^2}dy\\
=& \int_0^\infty \frac{y^p}{1+y}dy-\int_0^\infty\frac{y^p}{2+y}dy- \int_0^\infty\frac{y^p}{(2+y)^2}dy
\end{align}
Utilize the known integral
$J(a)=\int_0^\infty \frac {y^p}{a+y}dy= -\pi a^p \csc\pi p$
to evaluate
\begin{align}
& \int_0^\infty \frac{y^p}{1+y}dy=J(1)= -\pi \csc\pi p\\
 & \int_0^\infty \frac{y^p}{2+y}dy=J(2)= -\pi \ 2^p\csc\pi p\\
 & \int_0^\infty \frac{y^p}{(2+y)^2}dy=-\frac{d J(a)}{da}\bigg|_{a=2} = \pi \ 2^{p-1}p\csc\pi p\\
\end{align}
Plug above results into $I$ to obtain
$$I=\pi\ [2^{p-1}(2-p)-1]\csc\pi p
$$

Comment: I got to the partial fraction decomposition, but didn't know the "known integral" $J(a)$, and it seems very useful. Do you have a link to some proof?

Comment: @Zima It follows quickly from $\int_0^\infty\frac{y^p}{1+y} dy$ which is well known and you can search for links with Approach0

Comment: @FShrike, what is Approacho?

Comment: @Angelo https://approach0.xyz/search/

Comment: As far as I can see the integral $J(a) >0$ but the rhs $<0$ if $0<p<1$. Furthermore the integral is divergent.

Comment: @JanG   To break up the integral into those 3 integrals, the parameter $p$ needs to be restricted to $-1 < p < 0$ so that all 3 integrals converge.

Comment: @Random Variable True. But then we need an argument for $0 \le p< 2$. Analytic continuation?

Answer (score 2):

The substitution $ u = \frac{1-x}{1+x}$ shows that $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{1-p}(1-x)^{p}}{(1+x)^2} \, \mathrm dx = 2^{p-1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{u^{p}(1-u)^{1-p}}{u+1} \, \mathrm du.$$

In a [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4654456/16033) I showed that $$\int_{a}^{b} \frac{(x-a)^{p}(b-x)^{1-p}}{x-c} \, \mathrm dx=  \pi \, \csc(\pi p) \left(\left( (a-b)p+b-c \right)- \left(\frac{a-c}{b-c} \right)^{p} (b-c)\right), $$ where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$, $b >a$, $-1 < p < 2 $ and $c \notin [a,b].$

Using this result, we have $$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{1-p}(1-x)^{p}}{(1+x)^2} \, \mathrm dx &= 2^{p-1} \, \pi \csc(\pi p) \left(-p+2-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{p}(2) \right) \\ &= \pi \csc(\pi p) \left(2^{p-1}\left(2-p \right)-1 \right). \end{align}$$

---

Alternatively, I showed in my  [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4654456/16033) that  $$\int_{a}^{b} \frac{(x-a)^{p}(b-x)^{1-p}}{(x-c)(x-d)} \, \mathrm dx = - \pi \csc(\pi p) \left(1+ \left(\frac{a-c}{b-c} \right)^{p} \, \frac{b-c}{c-d} - \left(\frac{a-d}{b-d} \right)^{p} \, \frac{b-d}{c-d} \right), $$

where $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$, $b>a$, $-1<p<2$, $c \ne d$, and $c , d \notin [a,b]$.

Taking the limit as $d \to c$, we get

$$\int_{a}^{b} \frac{(x-a)^{p}(b-x)^{1-p}}{(x-c)^2} \, \mathrm dx = - \pi \csc(\pi p) \left(1+ \left(\frac{a-c}{b-c} \right)^{p} \, \frac{a(p-1)-bp+c }{a-c} \right).$$

Therefore, $$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{1-p}(1-x)^{p}}{(1+x)^2} \, \mathrm dx &=  - \pi \csc \left(\pi (1-p)\right ) \, \left(1+ \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^{1-p} \, \frac{0-(1-p)-1 }{1} \right) \\ &= \pi \csc(\pi p) \left(2^{p-1} (2-p)-1 \right). \end{align}$$

Comment: @GEdgar   It seems correct.  See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Nintegrate%5Bx%5E%281%2F2%29*%281-x%29%5E%281%2F2%29%2F%281%2Bx%29%5E2%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%5D) and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=pi*csc%28pi%2F2%29*%282%5E%281%2F2-1%29*%282-1%2F2%29-1%29).

Comment: You are OK.  I had the formula wrong.